# Sendmail not working for local GAE local development server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've enabled sendmail using the `--enable_sendmail=yes` option as described in [the GAE docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_mail) and am still not getting any emails (though the emails do appear in the logging messages). Simplified code looks like:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "admin@APPID.appspot.com"

msg = "Test message"

subject = "Test subject"

recipient = "{} <{}>".format('username', 'username@gmail.com')

mail.send_mail(sender=SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
               to=recipient,
               subject=subject,
               body=msg)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a From address it must correspond with your local machine. The sendmail handling function in the Mail Stub that google provides for its development server looks like:

```
...
try:
    child.stdin.write(mime_message.as_string())
    child.stdin.close()
...
```

The problem is that the From address passed to the `send_mail` method is in `mime_message` headers. Adding the following line as the first line in the try block removes that header from the mime message. This allows sendmail to use a default From address:

```
mime_message._headers = [x for x in mime_message._headers if x[0] != 'From']
```

The file with this function can be found at `/path/to/google_cloud_sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/mail_stub.py`